# How to get a list of files from a directory in C#

Tags: c#, windows

So, im working on a mp3 player in C# but i'm facing a problem.
I want to get all the files from a directory in a list, so you can select
the song you want to play.

This is the code to get the files ↓

```
string[] music = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3");
```

and to play it ↓

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = String.Join(" ", music);
wplayer.controls.play();
```

this works if there's only one file in the folder, but as soon there are multiple files in it, it doesn't work...

So I think the solution is to set all the files in a list so it starts at 0 and ends go's on and on, until there are no songs anymore. and it starts all over again then.

But, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already get all the files you want by:

```
string[] music = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3");
```

`GetFiles` return all files in the folder and with your search pattern as `*mp3`, it returns all MP3 files already.

The thing is, you do not need to do `string.Join` for the files, but play them one by one:

```
foreach (var musicurl in music){
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    wplayer.URL = musicurl; //get one by one
    wplayer.controls.play();
    //Logic to control how long a music is to be played
}
```

The reason why your current logic only works when you have exactly one MP3 file in your folder is because of the `string.Join` that you use.

To illustrate, this is what the `string.Join` do for in your `music` when you have more than one files. Suppose your `music` consists of:

```
C:\music1.mp3
C:\music2.mp3
```

When you do `string.Join`, your URL becomes:

```
C:\music1.mp3 C:\music2.mp3
```

Thus you cannot play the music. But when you only have one file, the string join does not affect:

```
C:\music1.mp3
```

Comment: @LuukWuijster note that I put: `//Logic to control how long a music is to be played` you got to add something to control how to choose the next song.

Comment: Oh yeah I see. But the only thing I can think of (and what I did) is to get the time of the track and then do await task.Delay(TimeOfTrack);

Isn't there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @LuukWuijster That is certainly one of the choices. Why not? ;) just add a little more delay for the transition (say, 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = wplayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("playlist");

string[] music = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3");

foreach (string file in music)
{
    WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = wplayer.newMedia(file);
    playlist.appendItem(media);
}

wplayer.currentPlaylist = playlist;
```